# How can I implement Cache-Control: public in Vercel

Tags: reactjs, caching, next.js, vercel

I need to Cache Control my personal site and I don't know how or where should I tell the browser to cache the site.

I wanna use
`Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000, immutable`
But don't know how as I'm using Next.js app hosted with Vercel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using Vercel you can [configure the headers](https://vercel.com/docs/cli#project-configuration/headers) in your `vercel.json` file.

```json
{
    "headers": [
        {
            "source": "/(.*)",
            "headers" : [
                {
                    "key" : "Cache-Control",
                    "value" : "public, max-age=31536000, immutable"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```